# plotting multiple sensor values using drawnow in python

Tags: python-2.7, drawnow

I am having 7 sensors which is connected to a micro controller , the controller a sends data to a pc using serial port , i am trying to plot the sensors values in real-time using python drawnow function , can anybody help me in giving the correct syntax for the same to plot the all the sensors in the same figure

Answer (score 0):

How about this for 4 sensors:

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import *

sensors = 4
x = dict([(s,[]) for s in range(0,sensors)])   # initialize dictionary of sensor stream values

def makePlot():
    plt.subplot(411)
    plt.plot(x[0],'r')
    plt.subplot(412)
    plt.plot(x[1],'g')
    plt.subplot(413)
    plt.plot(x[2],'b')
    plt.subplot(414)
    plt.plot(x[3],'c')

for i in range(0,100):  # simulate passage of time
    time.sleep(1)  # 1-sec delay for each loop

    for s in range(0,sensors):
        x[s].append(i*s)

    drawnow(makePlot)
```